# Is there any contradiction in both flagging as NAA and leaving a comment for newbies?

Tags: discussion, comments, not-an-answer

Sometimes there may some newbies who post comments as answers. If I flag these posts as Not An Answer, they will be deleted but the user may never know what they did wrong. On the other hand, if I just leave comments but don't flag the posts, the users can see the comments and know what they did wrong but the posts may not be deleted.

Is there any contradiction in both flagging and leaving comments for newbies?

Comment: The reviewers that handle the flag will probably leave an auto-comment, picking any of the available boilerplate texts.

Comment: Also remember that the user can still see their own deleted answer and comments thereon.

Comment: I'll take only few seconds to write a comment. So if you're worried about that, you can leave an informative message for OP.

Comment: Be prepared to see "Yeah I posted an answer because I can't comment yet" *a lot*.

Comment: @MarounMaroun He's worried that the OP won't be able to read the comment if the post is deleted.

Comment: This actually happened to me several times. I wrote longer, explanatory comment in hope OP will be able to understand why is his question downvoted - but when I posted the comment the question was deleted already.

Comment: @rene Those boilerplates really ought to be available in the [First Posts](http://serverfault.com/review/first-posts) and [Late Answers](http://serverfault.com/review/late-answers) queues as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you think you can add a constructive comment in addition to flagging, then please do! These sorts of comments are important because they teach new users about the rules of the site, and they will be visible to the post's author even after the post has been deleted.

Ideally these sorts of comments would be added as part of the community review process in the Low Quality Posts Queue, where reviewers can add a few different boilerplate comments. In the case you're describing (somebody has left a comment as an answer), there are a few relevant boilerplate comments:

#### Ask another question

```
This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it 
by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a 
bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to 
this question once you have enough 
[reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).
```

Preview:

> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different
>   question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask
>   Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a
>   bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw
>   more attention to this question once you have enough
>   [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

---

#### "Comment" answer

```
This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from 
an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, 
and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) 
you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
```

Preview:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
>   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post
>   - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient
>   [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will
>   be able to [comment on any
>   post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

---

#### "Thank you" answer

```
Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient 
[reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up 
questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found 
helpful.
```

Preview:

> Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient
>   [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will
>   be able to [vote up questions and
>   answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you
>   found helpful.

I have a slight variety that I use for "me too" posts:

---

#### "Me too" answer

```
Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the 
question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) 
you will be able to upvote questions that are helpful or [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) 
to draw more attention to a question.
```

Preview:

> Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as
>   the one described in the question. Once you have sufficient
>   [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will
>   be able to upvote questions that are helpful or [add a
>   bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw
>   more attention to a question.

While ideally these sorts of comments would be added through that queue, in practice many posts with NAA flags end up in the moderator flag queue not having been deleted and not having had a boilerplate comment added; in the past week I've added more than 200 boilerplate comments when handling NAA flags. If you think you can add constructive comments in addition to flagging then please do -- you're helping to teach a new user how to use the site and you're decreasing moderator workload.

Comment: Wouldn't it better if the devs popped up a banner with equivalent text, when the flag gets validated? Save on the comment noise, and on the workload for _everyone_? Like an automated refresher of the Help Centre contents for those who obviously haven't bothered to read it (or didn't care about what it said)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe (based on http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85858/253560) that users already get redirected to the help center from the deleted answer. The way I see it the comment noise isn't too worrisome because these answers are generally getting deleted anyways, so I'd want to try to communicate the rules as many ways as possible (comments plus message after deletion).